# Why my filter with input buttons doesn’t work while my searchbar filter does?

Tags: javascript, html

I made a searchbar filter and a filter with input buttons. The searchbar filter works but the input filter doesn't. How is that possible? Here you see the `searchbar` code and underneath there is the input button filter. First I made that filter with `buttons` who filter on the classnames but there are too many possibilities so with filtering on `textContent` it's the easiest I thought.

JavaScript

```js
//searchbar
function liveSearch() {
  let search_query = document.getElementById('myInput').value;

  //Use innerText if all contents are visible
  //Use textContent for including hidden elements
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (
      sheets[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(search_query.toLowerCase())
    ) {
      sheets[i].classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else {
      sheets[i].classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('myInput').oninput = liveSearch;

//buttons filter
let knop = document.querySelectorAll('#btn');

knop.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
    liveSearch2();
  }),
);

function liveSearch2() {
  let button = document.getElementById('btn').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(button.toLowerCase())) {
      sheets[i].classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else {
      sheets[i].classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById('btn').oninput = liveSearch2;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Search for music..." title="Type in a name" />

<div id="myBtnContainer">
  <p class="titeltje">Genre</p>
  <input value="Barok" type="button" class="btn" id="btn"></input>
  <input value="Classic" type="button" class="btn" id="btn"></input>
  <input value="Rennaisance" type="button" class="btn" id="btn"></input>
  <input value="Romantic" type="button" class="btn" id="btn"></input>
  <input value="Movies" type="button" class="btn" id="btn"></input>
</div>`
```

Comment: What is `sheets`? Please add all the necessary definitions to the snippet will run.

Comment: IDs need to be unique. You have multiple `id="btn"`. `let button = document.getElementById('btn').value` will always use the value of the first button, not the button that the user clicked on.

Comment: Pass `e.target.value` as an argument to `liveSearch2()`, and use that.

Comment: Sheets is `const sheets = document.querySelectorAll('.filterDiv');`  There are some `h1` and `p` in where it should filter on.

Comment: Ah yes. it will always take the value of the first button. How can I make it take the value of the button that is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always getting the value of the first button when you do

```
let button = document.getElementById('btn').value;
```

This doesn't get the button that the user clicked on.

Use `e.target` to get the button that the user clicked on, and get its value.

```js
knop.forEach((btn) =>
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
    liveSearch2(e.target.value);
  }),
);

function liveSearch2(button) {
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].textContent.toLowerCase().includes(button.toLowerCase())) {
      sheets[i].classList.remove('is-hidden');
    } else {
      sheets[i].classList.add('is-hidden');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But now i'm trying to undo that function when I click the button again. How can I do that?

Comment: You should probably be using checkboxes, not buttons.